# Reading large uncleaned data efficiently into R

Tags: r, large-data

I am trying to do calculations on a large data set (~80 million rows 9 columns) but the problem is that the dataset is uncleaned contains 9 unwanted rows(having different no and type of columns)repeating themselves every 2280 rows of rows of actual data.

Tried different options from basic (read.table) to sqldf , ff , data.frame but unable to read only the actual data and being new to R is added worry.The option working is **read.table(file, skip =9 , fill = T)** and subsetting it thereafter but that is reading the unwanted rows and taking ages and running out my memory.Tried and researched 100s of hours reading pdf but nothing explains in detail or its difficult to a beginner like me

It looks like:

```
ITEM: TIMESTEP  
0  
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS  
2280  
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp  
-6.16961 6.16961  
-6.16961 6.16961  
-6.16961 6.16961  
ITEM: ATOMS id mol type x y z ix iy iz   
1 1 1 -0.31373 3.56934 -0.560608 1 -1 6   
2 1 1 0.266159 3.08043 -1.20681 1 -1 6   
3 1 1 1.07006 3.55954 -1.09484 1 -1 6
```

I want to read the 9 column values by skipping the first 9 rows every n 2280 rows without running out of memory.

Specifications:
Windows 8 x64, 4 GB RAM, 512 GB SSD, Dual Core
x64 R

Comment: So what's the pattern? 9 bad, 2271 good, 9 bad, 2271 good, etc?

Comment: 80M rows x 9 cols is going to be tight regardless... if you assume is cell is 4 bytes: `(4*80e6*9)/1e9` is `2.88` gigs... and they likely will be more than just 4 bytes each... maybe try: `awk 'NR%2280==0' file.txt > filtered.txt` or something along those lines to filter outside R. Also look into `data.table`'s `fread()` for reading the filtered data in.

Comment: @Mrflick  The pattern is 9 bad, 2280 good, 9 bad, 2280 good.....

Comment: awk works thanks for that @anamnesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend downloading Cygwin64 on Windows. You can do fast processing on large data sets and send chunks to files which can then be processed in R.  Here's an example,

From the shell, remove the first 9 lines and sent the rest to `"myFile2.txt"`, where `"myFile.txt"` is the original data

```
$ tail -n +10 myFile.txt > myFile2.txt
```

Then, in R

```
> read.table('myFile2.txt')
#   V1 V2 V3        V4      V5        V6 V7 V8 V9
# 1  1  1  1 -0.313730 3.56934 -0.560608  1 -1  6
# 2  2  1  1  0.266159 3.08043 -1.206810  1 -1  6
# 3  3  1  1  1.070060 3.55954 -1.094840  1 -1  6
```

Answer (score 3):

### `fread()` / `data.table` solution:

as per my comment 4Gigs will be tight so you may need to do this in batches by specifying the `nrow=` argument to `fread()`.

### As per example:

The data sample you provided:

```
smp <- "ITEM: TIMESTEP  
0  
ITEM: NUMBER OF ATOMS  
2280  
ITEM: BOX BOUNDS pp pp pp  
-6.16961 6.16961  
-6.16961 6.16961  
-6.16961 6.16961  
ITEM: ATOMS id mol type x y z ix iy iz   
1 1 1 -0.31373 3.56934 -0.560608 1 -1 6
2 1 1 0.266159 3.08043 -1.20681 1 -1 6
3 1 1 1.07006 3.55954 -1.09484 1 -1 6"
```

First we read in the file but only seperating by line using `sep="\n"`.

```
library( data.table )

all_lines <- fread(smp, sep="\n", header=FALSE)
```

Then we drop the lines we don't want. Note that you can replace `c(1:9)` with whatever your repeating pattern of rows indexes are. It was not clear to me what this was so I leave that to you.

```
good_lines <- all_lines[-c(1:9)]
```

We then collapse this back into a large character string with `paste0(, collapse="\n")`:

```
collapsed <- paste0(good_lines$V1, collapse="\n")
```

We then capture this in the intended format by calling `fread()` on this character string:

```
what_I_want <- fread(collapsed,header=FALSE)
```

And in this case the result is:

```
what_I_want
# V1 V2 V3        V4      V5        V6 V7 V8 V9
# 1:  1  1  1 -0.313730 3.56934 -0.560608  1 -1  6
# 2:  2  1  1  0.266159 3.08043 -1.206810  1 -1  6
# 3:  3  1  1  1.070060 3.55954 -1.094840  1 -1  6
```

Comment: Cleaned the data with awk and read it into R directly with fread within a minute....Thanks for the right direction

Comment: @sharu2801 np. consider editing your post to reflect the solution method you used ( as in exact ). you asked to "read large uncleaned data into R" and this is what my answer is based on (and my comment based on awk is NOT). I suggest: First section "how to clean data on my system"/ "how to read the cleaned data into R efficiently".